# Please prove that $(a,b)=(c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let ordered set be defined as $(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. Then, how can we prove that $(a,b)=(c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$?

Please help.Thank you.

Comment: Well you know if $(a,b)=(c,b)$, then the singletons $\{a\}$ and $\{c\}$ have to be equal. That gives you $a=c$. $b=d$ is easy given that. I think the reverse should follow similarly.

Comment: @IanColey: You must also consider the possibility that $\{a\}=\{c,d\}$ and $\{a,b\}=\{c\}$. It does not give any new solutions, but it cannot be ignored.

Comment: Right, sorry. I was thinking too literally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT: One direction is trivial, so suppose that $\big\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\big\}=\big\{\{c\},\{c,d\}\big\}$. You need to consider two cases:

- $a=b$: Then your hypothesis is that $\big\{\{a\}\big\}=\big\{\{c\},\{c,d\}\big\}$. This implies that $\{c\}=\{c,d\}=\{a\}$; why? And that in turn implies that $c=d=a$; why?
- $a\ne b$: Then $\{c\}$ must be equal to $\{a\}$, not $\{a,b\}$; why? That implies that $a=c$, and to finish the argument you need only show why $b=d$.

Comment: Sir, please explain "why".

Comment: @Sush: Which one(s)? They’re all pretty easy, and you should be able to fill in the missing details for at least one of them.

Comment: Just explain the why after {c}={c,d}={a}

Comment: @Sush: The set $\big\{\{a\}\big\}$ has just one member, $\{a\}$, and $\big\{\{c\},\{c,d\}\big\}$ is the same set, so both $\{c\}$ and $\{c,d\}$ must be that same member: $\{c\}=\{a\}$, and $\{c,d\}=\{a\}$. If $\{c,d\}=\{a\}$, then $c\in\{a\}$ and $d\in\{a\}$; what does that tell you about $c$ and $d$?